# view is ignoring contentBinding

Tags: ember.js

I'm building a playlist. I have two models describing a json response from the server

```
App.ChartsModel = Em.Model.extend({
  playlist: Em.belongsTo('App.PlaylistModel', { key: 'playlist', embedded: true })
})

App.PlaylistModel = Em.Model.extend({
  description: Em.attr()
  uc_date: Em.attr()
})
```

The instances of these models are loaded into the controller successfully in the route. Then I have my primary template:

```
#playlists
  App.PlaylistView controllerBinding="controllers.playlist" contentBinding="content.playlist"
p {{content.playlist}}
```

Then the App.PlaylistView template looks like:

```
#playlist
  p {{this}}
  p {{model}}
```

Here is what renders:

```
<div id="playlists">
  <div id="playlist">
    <p>
      <App.PlaylistController:ember456>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <App.PlaylistModel:ember454>
  </p>
</div>
```

I expected the "#playlist" div to have a p-tag set with the instance of App.PlaylistModel.  Not sure why the contentBinding isn't taking effect.

Any ideas?

- **UPDATE** * It appears that setting the controllerBinding nullifies the contentBinding.  Is there a way to set the controller AND the content in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think loading the models into the controller is the right approach. I will assume that it's the PlayListController, so its model is a Playlist and you have another property called 'charts' with the Charts instance.

For the view, however, you should just use the controller as its *context* (not content) and access the models through that context. I would not mess with its controller or context bindings directly nor think of them as different. If you really need to specify things in a binding, you might try using a unique name e.g. `chartsBinding="controllers.playlist.charts"`. Your contentBinding may very well be working. You would access it in the template with `{{content}}`, not `{{this}}`.

Anyway, you may want to try specifying the controller as the view's context like:

```
#playlists
  App.PlaylistView contextBinding=controller
```

Then, in the App.PlaylistView template:

```
#playlist
  p {{this}}
  p {{charts}}
  p {{model}}
```

Should give you: playlist controller (the context), charts instance, and playlist instance.